GMail API "Precondition check failed." when trying to list messages
The Problem
I'm trying to use the GMail API via the Offical Google .NET Libraries. I'm building a ASP .NET 8 App with razor pages. I manage to sign the user in and store the token in the database. I can also retrieve the Token from the Database and get a new access token based on my stored refresh token. However, when I try to retrieve the messages I get a "BAD Request" response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Precondition check failed.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Precondition check failed.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "failedPrecondition"
      }
    ],
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
  }
}

What I've tried
First I request a new Access Token:
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
User-Agent = google-api-dotnet-client/1.68.0.0; User-Agent = (gzip)
refresh_token=***&grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=***.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=***

Which succeeds:
{
  "access_token": "***",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "id_token": "***"
}

Afterwards I try to request the messages:
https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages
User-Agent = ConsographKengraAdapterGoogle; User-Agent = google-api-dotnet-client/1.68.0.0; User-Agent = (gzip); x-goog-api-client = gl-dotnet/8.0.0 gdcl/1.68.0.3399; Authorization = Bearer ***

Which fails with the aforementioned error response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Precondition check failed.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Precondition check failed.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "failedPrecondition"
      }
    ],
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
  }
}

I'm not sure what could be the issue.

Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77300161/getting-precondition-check-failed-when-using-gmail-api-with-a-service-account

In my case I was using a freshly created google account for testing. Turns out, you have to activly add a gmail account to your google account which wasn't always the case.
After adding gmail to my google account it worked flawlessly.

Is your request correctly formatted In this type of structure?
string accessToken = "your_access_token";

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages");

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   
}
else
{
    var errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
